# Difference between date columns and output should be in hours

Tags: sql

```
select 
    sysdate, 
    reserved_date,  
    (sysdate-reserved_date) DIFF_HOURS 
from INVENTORY_NEW;
```

Currently the `DIFF_HOURS` is showing the difference in days, how can I display difference in hours?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `sysdate` suggests Oracle.

A simple way is to multiple the difference by 24:

```
select sysdate, reserved_date,
       (sysdate - reserved_date)*24 DIFF_HOURS
from INVENTORY_NEW;
```

If you want the value as an integer, then truncate the difference.